# How to use puppet modules in puppet client?

Tags: module, puppet

I have search many puppet module problem and seen the answer but still it doesn't solve my problem. I am new to puppet and have install puppet master and client. My /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp contains

```
node 'dn1.test.com'{
        include custom_utils
}
node 'client.test.com'{
        include custom_utils
}
class custom_utils {
package { ["nmap","telnet","vim-enhanced","traceroute"]:
        ensure => latest,
        allow_virtual => false,
        }
}
```

and when I run

> *puppet agent -t*

the puppet client works fine and install all the packages.

Now when I try to test modules I am not able to do it.

After installing module

> *puppet module install puppetlabs-mysql*

my puppet module shows

```
    puppet module list
/etc/puppet/modules
├── nanliu-staging (v1.0.3)
├── puppetlabs-mysql (v3.3.0)
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.6.0)
/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```

and I make changes to above site.pp as recommended in this sites as below

```
    node 'dn1.test.com'{
        include custom_utils
}

node 'client.test.com'{
        include custom_utils
        require puppetlabs-mysql
}
class custom_utils {
package { ["nmap","telnet","vim-enhanced","traceroute"]:
        ensure => latest,
        allow_virtual => false,
        }
}
```

But when i run puppet client

> *puppet agent -t*

I get

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class puppetlabs-mysql for client.test.com on node client.test.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

What else do I have to do, any idea you provide will be very helpful. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the description how to use [puppet mysql](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql) module ?

Puppet behaves as expected. First you have properly installed `puppet-mysql` module.
Next to use it, you **cannot** just write:

```
require puppetlabs-mysql
```

Depend on what you need, you **must** use resources defined by that module.
E.g

> If you want a server installed with the default options you can run include '::mysql::server'.
>
> All interaction for the server is done via mysql::server. To install the client, use mysql::client. To install bindings, use mysql::bindings.